# Alter view with hook_views_post_render and save results to cache

Tags: views, caching

How can I alter the results of a view with hook_views_post_render but save the altered output to cache, in order to avoid the overhead of altering the results on every request?

The ideal scanario should be like this: Is the cache expired -> Yes -> alter the view's output -> Save new output in cache, Otherwise don't alter the output.

Comment: Views caches query results and the rendered content. `post_render` happens _after_ both those caches are queried, by definition. You could manually re-cache the results of the post render, of course, but, by design, next time the View is executed your post_render code will obviously be run again. I guess you could maintain state yourself to decide whether that post render should run once/twice/whatever, but it would make much more sense to move your logic into a pre_render hook